# Unable to use Airplay, Remote App, or wireless printing

Tags: network, wifi, appletv, airplay

I have a regular home wireless network. The only issue is that, apparently, I'm unable to do things which require device-to-device connectivity (Airplay, Remote App on iPhone, or wireless printing). I'm trying to figure out what exactly is the issue at hand so I can fix it. I hadn't seen anything odd in the wireless settings. I'm not even sure how one can disable this feature.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I believe all those rely on the Bonjour service - that might help in searching for a resolution...

Comment: You'll want to search for things like mDNS, Bonjour, NAT-PMP or uPNP. These are the technologies used by the various services you mention. In general any consumer router made in the past several years will support all of these services. I recommend that you reset your router to factory settings, as a first step.